# Multi touch childview not getting events

Tags: android

I have an activity that has a linear layout and with some child views. If i touch with one finger outside a child view , then with another finger touch the child view no touch event is fired on the child view. If i touch the child view directly i get an event.

I override the touch event in the activity and call down to the child view, this works but the X,Y are from the parent and not relative to the child. How can the child view , the framelayout, get all touch events regardless of other finger touches outside it?

```
 @Override 
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event != null && clock != null) {
         event.offsetLocation(-frameLayout1.getLeft(),- frameLayout1.getTop());
         clock.onTouchEvent(event);

    }
     return false;
 };
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LearningLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/targetTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView" android:textSize="64dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textualTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView" android:textSize="64dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textualTime2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView" android:textSize="64dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/> 

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adUnitId="a14e531e444c51a"
                             ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does calculating x y for child solve your problem?

Comment: I have tried using `event.offsetLocation(-clock.getLeft(),- clock.getHeight());` , which didnt work. Is there a cleaner way than this without directly calling the childview onTouchEvent ?

Comment: Are looking for X and Y to determine which view is clicked??

Comment: No, i was hoping there is something in the framework that can direct touch events to the childview without extra calculations.

Comment: Why do want it to work with multiple touches like you described? this is not un expected behaviour. is it something your app requires?

Comment: The app is a clock that allows a user to drag hands to a time. Its for kids but sometimes kids have their fingers on the edge of the screen and then touch the clock and the clock does not respond only when touching the clock directly with one finger it responds.Really i want to ignore touches outside the clock.

Comment: Good Luck :) I am really sleepy. I think the solution is not that hard. you can do a workaround since you have X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the clock.getLeft() and clock.getTop() were returning 0 .The clock is a view subclasss inside the framelayout. If i use the framelayout getLeft() and getTop() it returns the right offset and works.
Is there a better way than calling the childview touch event and offsetting?